# In AmCharts, how can I pull the visible coordinates of the categoryAxis based on the scrollbar?

Tags: amcharts

I have a an AmChart, JavaScript chart, column chart with scroll.
I'd like to be able to pull the category axis data for the min and the max values that are currently being displayed in the chart.

Example: 
If I have 0-10 on the x-axis and I zoom to 4-6, I want to be able to reference the data on point 4 and point 6.

I am new to AmCharts so hopefully I am just missing something simple but I can't seem to figure this out.

Here is a link to a chart I made:
https://live.amcharts.com/U4YmV/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [zoomed](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomed) event to capture the `startIndex` and `endIndex` from its event object.

In the example below, `zoomedData` is the zoom selection.

```
chart.addListener("zoomed", zoomed);

function zoomed (e) {
  var chart = e.chart,
      data = chart.dataProvider,
      zoomedData = data.slice(e.startIndex, e.endIndex + 1);
}
```

Please check the example here: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/246e8f826610e848b7389fb85657348a

Comment: Thanks. @Darlesson I was thinking of going down that approach but I wanted to make sure AmCharts didn't store this information already.